# Typed kwargs in Julia

Tags: types, julia, variadic-functions, keyword-argument

Is it possible to type function kwargs in Julia?

The following works for standard `Vararg`s.

```
function int_args(args::Integer...)
    args
end

int_args(1, 2, 3)
# (1, 2, 3)

int_args(1, 2, 3.0)
# ERROR: MethodError: `int_args` has no method matching int_args(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64)
```

However, when applying this same syntax to kwargs, all function calls seem to error.

```
function int_kwargs(; kwargs::Integer...)
    kwargs
end

int_kwargs(x=1, y=2)
# ERROR: MethodError: `__int_kwargs#0__` has no method matching __int_kwargs#0__(::Array{Any,1})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normal keyword arguments can have types, as in `function f(x; a::Int=0)`, but this doesn't work for "rest" keyword arguments. Also note that since we currently don't dispatch on keyword arguments, the `a::Int` in this case is a type assertion and not a dispatch specification.

It looks like this case is not handled well, and needs a better error message at least. I'd encourage you to file an issue at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues.

I'm not sure what the syntax `x::T...` should mean for keyword arguments. In the case of varargs, it's clear that each element of `x` should have type `T`, but for rest keyword arguments each element is actually a symbol-value pair. Of course we could give it the meaning you describe (all values have type `T`), but this doesn't seem to come up very often. Keyword arguments tend to be quite heterogeneous, unlike varargs which are more like lists or arrays.

Comment: I will file an issue. Thank you!

Comment: @2Cubed, did you end up filing an issue?  I just ran into the same confusion myself.