# dealing with types in kwargs in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I use `kwargs` in a Julia function and declare their types for speed?

```
function f(x::Float64; kwargs...)
    kwargs = Dict(kwargs)
    if haskey(kwargs, :c)
        c::Float64 = kwargs[:c]
    else
        c::Float64 = 1.0
    end
    return x^2 + c
end

f(0.0, c=10.0)
```

yields:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: multiple type declarations for "c"
```

Of course I can define the function as `f(x::Float64, c::Float64=1.0)` to achieve the result, but I have MANY optional arguments with default values to pass, so I'd prefer to use kwargs.

Thanks.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240527/typed-kwargs-in-julia)

Comment: You don't need kwarg splatting here; just use regular keyword arguments.

Comment: I think there's one thing to really clear up here: declaring types doesn't "give speed". If the function is type-stable, then types can be inferred, and so it will effectively declare types without you doing it. If the function is not type-stable, then declaring types could make it type stable (by performing conversions on anything you try to save into the variable), and that's why it would be faster, not because of the declaration itself. But if it's a problem that can be fixed by simple conversions, you might want to use type assertions instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in another answer, this really only matters if you're going to have a type instability. If you do, the answer is to layer your functions. Have a top layer which does type checking and all sorts of setup, and then call a function which uses dispatch to be fast. For example,

```
function f(x::Float64; kwargs...)
    kwargs = Dict(kwargs)
    if haskey(kwargs, :c)
        c = kwargs[:c]
    else
        c = 1.0
    end

    return _f(x,c)
end
_f(x,c) = x^2 + c
```

If most of your time is spent in the inner function, then this will be faster (it might not be for very simple functions). This allows for very general usage too, where you have have a keyword argument be by default `nothing` and do and `if nothing ...` which could setup a complicated default, and not have to worry about the type stability since it will be shielded from the inner function.

This kind of high-level type-checking wrapper above a performance sensitive inner function is used a lot in DifferentialEquations.jl. Check out the high-level wrapper [for the SDE solvers](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/blob/master/src/sde/sde_solve.jl#L39) which led to nice speedups by insuring type stability (the inner function is `sde_solve`) (or check out the `solve` for `ODEProblem`, it's much more complex since it handles conversions to different pacakges but it's the same idea).

A simpler answer for small examples like yours may be possible after [this PR merges](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/16580).

---

To fix some confusion, here's a declaration form:

```
function f(x::Float64; kwargs...)
    local c::Float64 # Ensures the type of `c` will be `Float64`
    kwargs = Dict(kwargs)
    if haskey(kwargs, :c)
        c = float(kwargs[:c])
    else
        c = 1.0
    end

    return x^2 + c
end
```

This will force anything that saves to `c` to convert to a `Float64` or error, resulting in a type-stability, but is not as general of a solution. What form you use really depends on what you're doing.

Lastly, there's also the type assert, as @TotalVerb showed:

```
function f(x::Float64; c::Float64=1.0, kwargs...)
   return x^2 + c
end
```

That's clean, or you could assert in the function:

```
  function f(x::Float64; kwargs...)
    kwargs = Dict(kwargs)
    if haskey(kwargs, :c)
        c = float(kwargs[:c])::Float64
    else
        c = 1.0
    end

    return x^2 + c
end
```

which will cause convertions only on the lines where the assertion occurs (i.e. the @TotalVerb form won't dispatch, so you can't make another function with `c::Int`, and it will only assert (convert) when the keyword arg is first read in).

---

#### Summary

1. The first solution will dispatch to be type stable in `_f` no matter what type the user makes `c`, and so if `_f` is a long calculation, this will get pretty much optimal performance, but for really quick calls it will have dispatch overhead.
2. The second solution will fix any type stability by forcing anything you set `c` to be a `Float64` (it will try to convert, and if it can't, error). Thus this gets speed by forcing type stability, or erroring.
3. The assert in the keyword spot (@TotalVerb's answer) is the cleanest, but won't auto-convert later (so you could get a type-instability. But if you don't accidentally convert it later, then you have type stability, types can be inferred, and so you'll get optimal performance) and you can't extend it to cases where the function has `c` passed in as other types (no dispatch).
4. The last solution is pretty much the same as 3, except not as nice. I wouldn't recommend it. If you're doing something complicated with asserts, you likely are designing something wrong or really want to do something like the first (dispatch in a longer function call which is type stable).

But note that [dispatch with version 3 may be fixed in the near future](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/16580), which would allow you to have a different function with `c::Float64` and `c::Int` (if necessary). Hopefully your solution is in here somewhere.

Comment: Right, my function is more complicated, so I need to ensure type stability for speed.
The problem is that in the above function in your post (and mine), I get an error `ERROR: syntax: multiple type declarations for "c"`.

Comment: I was just using it the way you had it. You shouldn't use type declarations for this, just use the constructors and conversion methods to change the types around. If you need to declare types for some reason (clarity), at the top of the code do `local c::Float64`.

Comment: So isn't this an example of type instability? If you don't tell the compiler what type `c` is, then won't it be slower? Or is the compiler smart enough to see the `float` conversion and know that `c` is always a float? Thanks.

Comment: It could be. But if `_f` is type-stable and it's where you spend all of your time, then you don't need to worry. If you know that you always want `c` to be a `Float64`, then you can declare it at the top: `local c::Float64` and so anything that you try to set `c` will convert to a `Float64` or error. That would be another way of doing what you want.

Comment: Note that if you truly have a type-instability, you wouldn't be able to declare `c` because there would be at least two different types you'd have to conditionally declare it. That's why I showed the case with no declaration: it'll generally handle the problem (in a way that's appropriate if the inner function `_f` takes all of the time). If you can always convert it to `Float64` from the `kwargs`, then you don't have a type-instability.

Comment: You can remove the type instability with `c = Float64(kwargs[:c])`, or a type declaration as @ChrisRackauckas mentioned. `float(kwargs[:c])` is not inferrable because `float` returns `BigFloat` for some values.

Answer (score 2):

Note that declaring types does not give you increased performance; you may wish to relax the type constraints on `x` and `c` for your code to be more generic. Anyway, this is probably what you want:

```
function f(x::Float64; c::Float64=1.0, kwargs...)
    return x^2 + c
end
```

See the [keyword arguments](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#keyword-arguments) section of the manual.

Comment: Doesn't declaring the type speed up [a more complicated] code if there is type instability inside of the function?
Right, I see your way of doing it, but I have MANY optional arguments with defaults that I need to assign. I guess it is fine to just list them all.

Comment: Don't you have to list all the arguments anyway? It's just a matter of whether it's done compactly in the parameter list, or verbosely as `if` statements in the code, and I prefer the former.

Comment: @Cokes Also, declaring the type in a function signature does not remove type instabilities inside of the function. You are probably thinking about local definitions like `local x::T` to insert `convert`s to remove type instabilities, which can indeed speed up code. However, declaring argument types will not speed up code — if there is a type instability, it still needs to be addressed.

Comment: Note that in this case `c` has a type-assertion, not a type declaration. You could change it later to an `Int` in your code if this is done, and you can't write a dispatch for if `c` is another type ([you can't do dispatch on kwargs](http://julia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/methods/?highlight=keyword#note-on-optional-and-keyword-arguments)). So this works (and is type stable) only if you want to do an auto-convert of whatever people gave you to a `Float64` before storing it into `c`, and you don't accidentally change the type (it won't stop you).

Comment: Type declarations can prevent some accidental type mistakes, but in general it's better to write type-stable code in the first place, instead of relying on `convert` to fix problems.

Comment: Yeah, this is all about giving a set of options and letting someone chose the right ones knowing the pros and cons.

Comment: With this solution, as opposed to the `kwargs...` splatting one, it is unnecessary to declare any types unless you are modifying the arguments. Declaring argument types is not useful here in any event.

Comment: I agree. Declaring the types form likely isn't the solution he wants (though it has uses). For this simple example, this is the best form. For larger functions, you may want more robustness, either dispatching so it always works on whatever type you're given, or declaring so it will also convert (say, you call a package which may have some type-stability issues). It all depends.