# Specify the type of variable keyword arguments in Julia

Tags: julia

Referring to the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/index.html#Keyword-Arguments-1), I can define a function like this:

```
function f(x; y=0, kwargs...)
    ###
end
```

Making it somewhat more complex:

```
function f(x,args...; y=0, kwargs...)
    ###
end
```

If I need a specific type for the arguments, I write:

```
function f(x::Int64,args::Float64...; y::Int64=0, kwargs::Float64...)
    ###
end
```

this is valid for the `x`, `args` and `y` arguments but not for `kwargs`, as I get an error when I try:

```
julia> f(1,1.1,1.2;y=9,x=3.6,g=5.6)

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching #f#49(::Int64, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Float64,Tuple{Symbol,Symbol},NamedTuple{(:x, :g),Tuple{Float64,Float64}}}, ::typeof(f), ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  #f#49(::Int64, ::Float64, ::Any, ::Int64, ::Float64...) at REPL[193]:3
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::getfield(Main, Symbol("#kw##f")))(::NamedTuple{(:y, :x, :g),Tuple{Int64,Float64,Float64}}, ::typeof(f), ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Vararg{Float64,N} where N) at .\none:0
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

So how do I specify the type of variable keyword arguments?

Comment: I think that has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240527/typed-kwargs-in-julia

Comment: It seems not possible :(

Comment: I don't know if that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240527/typed-kwargs-in-julia) was exactly an answer (reason to close this post), well I found other alternatives, [dealing with types in kwargs in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601800/dealing-with-types-in-kwargs-in-julia?noredirect=1&lq=1) on Stackoverflow and [Typed keyword vararg](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/typed-keyword-vararg/26961) on Julialang, maybe I can help someone